# How can I count unique fields in a file?

Tags: perl, awk

I have some text files in a folder. The data of the text files are shown below.

```
USA     Germany   23-12 
USA     Germany   23-12 
USA     Germany   23-12 
France  Germany   15-12
France  Germany   15-12
France  Italy     25-50
China   China     30-32
China   China     30-32
```

I would like to count the unique numbers of each country in the first and second columns based on the numbers of third column. I need to save the outputs into another folder as the file names of input.

Desired output

```
USA       1
Germany   2
France    2
Italy     1
China     2
```

Comment: I wonder who upvoted this. How did you get the numbers in the second column of the output?

Comment: @perreal "unique numbers of each country in the first and second columns based on the numbers of third column" -- yeah it adds up to the numbers he says

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
perl -lane'
  $F[2] .= 1 if $F[0] eq $F[1] and $s{$F[0]};
  $s{$_}{$F[2]} = 1 for @F[0,1]; 
  END { printf("$_\t%s\n", scalar keys %{$s{$_}}) for sort keys %s }
' file
```

and if order matters,

```
perl -lane'
  $F[2] .= 1 if $F[0] eq $F[1] and $s{$F[0]};
  push(@r,$s{$_} ? () : $_), $s{$_}{$F[2]} = 1 for @F[0,1]; 
  END { printf("$_\t%s\n", scalar keys %{$s{$_}}) for @r }
' file
```

output

```
USA     1
Germany 2
France  2
Italy   1
China   2
```

Comment: @janos yes, but it seems there is an error either in OP input or output

Comment: @mpapec Thank you for your answer. china should be 2. It's not a mistake.

Comment: @mpapec Your code worked well for single file. How can I change the code for multiple files?

Comment: @user3122011 just put them on command line => `perl '..' file1 file2 file3`

Answer (score 1):

Given this `awk` code in `parse.awk`:

```
function get_name(name_colon_x) {
    return substr(name_colon_x, 1, index(name_colon_x, ":") - 1)
}
{
    u1[$1 ":" $3]
    u2[$2 ":" $3]
}
END {
    for (i in u1) u[get_name(i)]++
    for (i in u2) u[get_name(i)]++
    for (i in u) print i, u[i]
}
```

And your data in `data.txt`, then:

```
$ awk -f parse.awk data.txt
USA 1
France 2
Germany 2
China 2
Italy 1
```

Comment: +1 I think it is an interesting solution. I just wonder it you could have avoided using the function?

Comment: @janos Thanks for your answer. The last character of the first column doesn't print in my output. Also, I would like to print the outputs to another folder with the filenames of input. How can I change your program?

Comment: @user3122011 I don't understand your problem with the last character of the first column... But in any case the Perl solution of mpapec is better. For the 2nd part of your problem, I think it will be best to ask another question, and if you don't want it to get closed, you have to demonstrate some effort: try to make something work, show what you tried, and then ask for help.